# Swift present to another page not clear cache

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

i use below code `ViewControllerHome` :

```
var myValue = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
}

@objc func handleActionChat(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Val : \(myValue)"
    myValue = 1
    print("Val : \(myValue)"
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var goController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIndex")
    goController.roomId = self.sendRoom
    self.present(goController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

First open `ViewControllerHome` and click button result is :

```
0
1
```

If i go to `ViewControllerHome` again and click button result is :

```
1
1
```

Why not clear cache work ?

I want if i open every time, get `01` result

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are setting `var myValue = 0` only once.

If you want to set it back to zero whenever the view controller appears, then reset `myValue` whenever the view controller appears:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    myValue = 0
}
```